# ¿Por qué cuando uso la función gets() en c me da un error al copilar el programa?

Tags: c

Cuando lo compilo me da un error en la función `gets()`:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

char frase[30];
printf("Escriba una frase:");
gets(frase);
printf("%s",frase);
return 0;

}
```

Al compilarlo con `gcc` me sale error en la función `gets()`.

Comment: "*Al copilarlo con gcc me sale error en la función `gets()`*" ¿Qué error?

Comment: Kelvin, a la hora de preguntar sobre un error, AÑADE dicho error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función **`gets()`** está obsoleto y ha sido eliminado de la librería estándar de C debido a [su alta peligrosidad y no recomendación de uso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

tendrías que usar [**`fgets()`**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm), en donde tiene tres argumentos: un puntero destino, el tamaño del array y un puntero de entrada, por ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char frase[30];
    
    printf("Escriba una frase: ");
    
    fgets(frase, sizeof(frase), stdin);
    
    printf("%s",frase);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
// Escriba una frase: hola mundo
// hola mundo
```